# Rails - Model for movie watched status?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a simple Model with **Movies** and a model for **Users**. Whats the best way to save which movies has been seen by a user? Should i create a "seen_movie" model? And a Controller for it? How should the action to toggle the status been called? I thought about something like this:

Model:

```
class SeenMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :movie

    def self.has_seen?(user)
        @has_seen = SeenMovie.find_by_user(user)
        return @has_seen
    end
end
```

Controller:

```
 class SeenMoviesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_login

    def update # any other name? how to call this action?
        if has_seen?(current_user)
            render text: "delete record"
        else
            render text: "create record"
        end
    end

    private

    def seen_movie_params
        params.require(:rating).permit(:movie_id)
    end
end
```

I am not sure if this works and if it is a good way. For me it doesn't looks like a good way to toggle a simple state...

Info: Im very new in Rails (came from PHP)

Comment: Your code looks okay so far. This isn't a "simple state". It's a many-to-many relation. What do your `User` and `Movie` classes look like?

Comment: `USER MODEL - has_many :seen_movies, dependent: :destroy` and 
`MOVIE MODEL - has_many :seen_movies, dependent: :destroy` - 
so its ok to create a extra controller/model for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would handle it:

In your model:

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :seen_movies
  has_many :movies, through: :seen_movies

  def has_seen?(movie)
    movies.where(id: movie.id).first.present?
  end
end

class Movie < AR::Base
  has_many :seen_movies
  has_many :users, through: :seen_movies
end
```

In your controller:

```
class SeenMoviesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_login

    def update
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
      if current_user.has_seen?(@movie)
        render text: "delete record"
      else
        render text: "create record"
      end
    end

    private

    def seen_movie_params
      params.require(:rating).permit(:movie_id)
    end
end
```

In your views:

```
<% @movies.each do |movie| %>
  <%= link_to "Seen it!", seen_movie_path(movie_id: movie.id), method: :put %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Looks good. I will move now the `has_seen?` to the user model. it was defently in the wrong model. how do i call the update action with a link/button?

Comment: Perfect nice your the best! Its working how it should. =) Accepted your Answer.